# Sending periodic location updates to server using async task android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to develop an application that send locations periodically to a server through http post. I have tried the async task in the following code. I am new to android programming. I get the error "failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 8080): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)" and "E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1" when I run this code. Please help me out

```
package com.example.vikram.locationinterval;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.net.UnknownServiceException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.security.Permission;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    TextView txtLat,content;
    protected static int intervalInMillis = 500;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        content    =   (TextView)findViewById( R.id.content );

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, intervalInMillis, 0.5f, this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        txtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        txtLat.setText("Latitude:" + location.getLatitude() + ", Longitude:" + location.getLongitude() + "\n now = " + now);
        try{

            System.out.println("\nTesting 2 - Send Http POST request");
            new MyAsyncTask(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()),String.valueOf(location.getLongitude())).execute();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //System.out.println(ex.getCause());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Log.d("Latitude", "disable");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Log.d("Latitude","enable");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Log.d("Latitude","status");
    }

    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double> {

        protected String latitude,longitude;

        protected MyAsyncTask(String lat,String lon){
            this.latitude = lat;
            this.longitude = lon;
        }

        @Override
        protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                postData(this.latitude, this.longitude);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Double result){

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "command sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


        public void postData(String Lat,String Lon) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
            // Create data variable for sent values to server

            String data = URLEncoder.encode("Latitude", "UTF-8")
                    + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Lat, "UTF-8");

            data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("Longitude", "UTF-8") + "="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(Lon, "UTF-8");
            System.out.println(data);

            String text = "";
            BufferedReader reader=null;



            // Send data
            try
            {

                // Defined URL  where to send data
                URL url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2:8080/GetSomeRest/webresources/service");

                // Send POST data request

                String charset = "UTF-8";
                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(5000);
                System.out.println("coonnected.: ");

                Permission p = conn.getPermission();
                System.out.println("permission: " + p.toString());
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=" + charset);
                System.out.println("output gate opened.."+conn.toString());
                OutputStream wr;
                try {
                    //conn.connect();
                    wr = conn.getOutputStream();
                    if(wr == null){
                        System.out.println("-> no stream!");
                    }
                    else {
                        wr.write(data.getBytes(Charset.forName(charset)));

                        //wr.flush();
                        wr.close();
                    }

                } catch (UnknownServiceException use){
                    System.out.println("error unknown server: "+use.getMessage());
                } catch (IOException connOI){
                    System.out.println("error io stream: "+connOI.getMessage());
                } catch (Exception connOSW){
                    System.out.println("error writing to stream: "+connOSW.getMessage());
                }
                // Get the server response

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;

                // Read Server Response
                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    // Append server response in string
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }


                text = sb.toString();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                try
                {

                    reader.close();
                }

                catch(Exception ex) {}
            }

            // Show response on activity
            content.setText( text  );

        }

    }



    }
```

Comment: Is your server and emulator running in the same network?

Comment: @PrerakSola I am running the app on my phone, it is using cellular connection. So no, it is not the same network.

Comment: Your server and phone should be in the same network. Also, the ip `10.0.2.2` is used by emulator to communicate to the machine on which it is running. So, you need to change it to the ip given to your server machine by the router.

Comment: @PrerakSola the problem is, I cannot connect my phone to wifi. And I am not using the emulator. I changed the ip to 192.168.2.140 which is the server"s ip (wired). So in short, I am trying to talk to the server through the cellular data of my phone and cannot get it working. Sorry if I am being a bit stupid with my question :/

Comment: They won't communicate with your current setup. Create a hotspot on your phone and connect your server to it.

Comment: @PrerakSola Okay I will try that, if I do that, I use the ip 10.0.2.2 ? and is there no way to just connect to a server using cellular connection ?

Comment: No, Your mobile hotspot will assign a different ip to your server. You need to use that. Also, if you want to access it via cellular network you need to host your server side code on a service like amazon aws.

Comment: @PrerakSola getting wifi to work on my phone is not possible at the moment :/ I can't create a mobile wifi hotspot. So I guess it is not possible to set this up through my phone. Please let me know if there is an alternative. Sorry for too many questions. Thanks anyway. :)